# Is Netflix's "Daredevil" a prerequisite for "Age of Ultron"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, suggested-order, avengers-age-of-ultron, daredevil-2015

I'm trying to set my friend up with an MCU binge to make sure he's all caught up for *Age of Ultron*. I feel kind of bad already piling two seasons of *S.H.I.E.L.D.* and *Agent Carter* and two movies on him, so I was wondering: **Without spoiling the movie,** can you tell me if *Daredevil* is worth adding to my friend's load before *Age of Ultron*?

(I plan to force him to watch it at some point regardless, just wondering how absolutely necessary it is that that some point be before *Age of Ultron*.)

Comment: Not in any way a prerequisite for Ultron...but it is much better than Ultron.

Comment: I'd say that the only films you really *need* to have seen going into Age of Ultron are Avengers 1 and Winter Soldier.

Comment: @evilsoup The last Marvel movie I'd seen was Iron Man 2, years ago, and I understood Age of Ultron just fine. They really do a pretty good job of setting everything up, as long as you have even a minor awareness of the names of the characters.

Comment: So far Daredevil is far more "separate" from the rest of the MCU than anything else -- very few references to other things.

Comment: “I feel kind of bad already piling two seasons of Agents of SHIELD” — as well you should!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Only kind of. Then I remember what an awesome show it is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nope. None of the events or characters in *Daredevil* intersect, influence, or interact with the goings-on of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. You can watch *Daredevil* later on, and not miss anything in *Age of Ultron* (which is to say, your friend should watch *Daredevil* at some point, it's quite good).

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, the world in the movie and TV versions will be kept separate, in order to keep the movie fans from having to follow all the different TV series and to keep complications (such as Agent Coulson being dead in the movies but alive in the TV series) from becoming an issue.

[Here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/merrillbarr/2015/04/23/marvel-avengers-age-of-ultron/) is a link that talks about the seperation, and the interview where it is brought up:

Comment: Well, mostly separate.  Agents of SHIELD has some intertwining with Age of Ultron (particularly Theta Protocol) and two episodes that touch on Thor movies, but not enough that you need either to see the other

Comment: However if you _do_ intend to watch both, it is important to be aware that watching episodes of AOS set after CA:TWS and (presumably) Age of Ultron will spoil the respective movie - and, if you care, vice versa (i.e. if you watched CA:TWS you already know what's coming for the first season of AOS). None of this applies to Daredevil at least not in regards to AOU.

Comment: Actually, Agents has a lot of episodes, and then BAM after a movie is released, here they are picking up the pieces.  The TV viewer is left wondering, "What happened? What 'mess' are they cleaning up in S01E15-E16?" etc. <- all comes from watching the the correct movies: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/marvel-cinematic-universe-timeline-avengers/ Heck, Agents starts off with S01 E01 with "Centipedes": What these are 'centipedes' they talk of? <- again, comes from watching the correct movie. I've myself been slowly catching up and watching the Marvel Universe: the link above is paramount!

Comment: @eduncan911: What do you mean regarding _Centipede_? As far as I know, Centipede was introduced in "Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D." and has not been mentioned in any other MCU media.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet correct - that is when they first "mention" the things defined at Centipede! But "where did they come from? Where did the Alien tech originate?" are the questions that the first Avengers movie can only answer. My point was you can watch movies mostly without TV; but, not the other way around. There are many things mentionrd in Agents that only comes from info shown in the movies.